AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'version' in my imports
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision

and getting following error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[8], line 4
      2 import torch.nn as nn
      3 import torch.optim as optim
----> 4 import torchvision
      5 import torchvision.transforms as transforms
      6 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File d:\Python\CNN PyTorch\venv\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\__init__.py:10
      7 # Don't re-order these, we need to load the _C extension (done when importing
      8 # .extensions) before entering _meta_registrations.
      9 from .extension import _HAS_OPS  # usort:skip
---> 10 from torchvision import _meta_registrations, datasets, io, models, ops, transforms, utils  # usort:skip
     12 try:
     13     from .version import __version__  # noqa: F401

File d:\Python\CNN PyTorch\venv\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\__init__.py:2
      1 from .alexnet import *
----> 2 from .convnext import *
      3 from .densenet import *
      4 from .efficientnet import *

File d:\Python\CNN PyTorch\venv\Lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\convnext.py:9
      6 from torch.nn import functional as F
   2213     import importlib
   2214     return importlib.import_module(f".{name}", __name__)
-> 2216 raise AttributeError(f"module '{__name__}' has no attribute '{name}'")

AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'version'


This question is similar to: AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'version'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

welcome [tour] [ask] and always use the search function
